# jQuery remote validation works only on 2nd click

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to set up a remote validation with the jQuery validation plugin 1.8.0 (and JQuery 1.5.2).

It works fine for "required" and "maxlength" but the remote validation works ONLY after the 2nd click (validation), or if any of the other errors has been fired before.

The validation is performed correctly and an error message is displayed but the first time, the validation returns true (even if an error is displayed). This is a problem since the form will be submitted with an error.

Here is my code (simplified):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
         $( "#check" ).click(function(){
            var valid = $("#myForm").validate(
                 {rules: {
                       groupName:{
                            required:true,
                            maxlength:40,
                            remote: {
                                url: 'ajaxCheck.php', // returns always a dummy string: "Simulate an error message" (JSON encoded)
                                type: "post",
                                data: {
                                    groupName: function() {
                                            return $("#groupName").val()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            ).form();
            alert(valid); // Returns true at the first call, and then false
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="myForm" action="">
   <label for="groupName">Group name</label>
   <input type="text" maxlength="40" size="45" value="my test" id="groupName" name="groupName">
</form>
<input type="button" value="Check form"   id="check" >
```

The ajaxCheck.php contains:

```
require_once ('Zend/Json/Encoder.php');
echo Zend_Json_Encoder::encode("Simulate an error message");
```

The JSON response seems to be correctly encoded (checked with Firebug).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I tried also jQuery 1.6 but had other problems on IE8.

Comment: Yes, jQuery validation plugin [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/)[/link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not waiting for validation to occur before using the return value. The reason is that validation requires an ajax request, and you're not waiting for it. The proper way to do this is to include any code you want to run after validation inside of a *callback*. In the validation plugin there is an `invalidHandler` that is called when the validation fails. You use it by adding it to the options object that you pass to `validate()` like so:

```
$(function() {
         $( "#check" ).click(function(){
            var valid = $("#myForm").validate(
                 {rules: {
                       groupName:{
                            required:true,
                            maxlength:40,
                            remote: {
                                url: 'ajaxCheck.php', // returns always a dummy string: "Simulate an error message" (JSON encoded)
                                type: "post",
                                data: {
                                    groupName: function() {
                                            return $("#groupName").val()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    invalidHandler: function(form, validator){
                            alert('invalid input'); //note this is called ONLY IF validation fails
                    }
                }
            ).form();
        });
   });
```

The validation plugin has a number of callbacks that are called based on validation results. **[Take a look at them here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate)** (click on "options" and look for functions that are "callbacks".)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this code but I'm a bit confused now. If I validate the form with an empty field, the "invalid input" message is displayed twice (is this handler fired for each error ? (the required and the remote error in this case).

Comment: first of all: what is this `.form()` function that you call on the form? Does it submit the form?

Comment: i don't think it's an issue of invalidHandler firing for each error, but most likely validation is running twice for some reason. Perhaps that `form()` function causes an extra validation? I'm not sure. You could try to set the onsubmit of the form = to the validation function and get rid of the click handler on that button.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. It works now ! The form was checked twice (I removed the click handler). Best regards. Matt